# FFMPEG multi-channel conversion (dts -> ac3) reverts to 2 channel when also adding aac stereo stream. Why?

Tags: ffmpeg

Assume the origin file contains 2 streams, one HD video and other DTS-MA multi-channel audio. The following produces a functioning .mkv with copied video and 5.1 AC3 soundtrack. The -map statements are optional in this case.

```
ffmmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 ac3 -ac 6 output.mkv
```

Now add the aac stereo downmix stream...

```
ffmmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 ac3 -ac 6 -c:a:1 aac -ac 2 -b:a:1 256k output.mkv
```

This outputs the two audio streams, but both are two-channel stereo. Omitting the downmix "-ac 2" argument restores 6 channels to both audio streams, but this isn't what I want. The final downmix argument has a global effect, controlling both conversions. Is this a bug, or is there a command line error?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [stream type specifier](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1) to `-ac`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 ac3 -ac:a:0 6 -c:a:1 aac -ac:a:1 2 -b:a:1 256k output.mkv
```

Yes, it is odd that you need to tell `-ac`, an audio option, to use the `a` (audio) specifier.

Comment: Thanks, llogan. That seems to be the solution.